# Setting control property in DataTemplate does not work as expected

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate

I have custom control:

```
public class TestTextBox : TextBox
{
    public TestTextBox()
    {
        Text = "ctor text";
    }
}
```

And xaml that uses this control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <!-- 1. Use TestTextBox directly -->
    <controls:TestTextBox Text="xaml text"/>

    <!-- 2. Use TestTextBox in DataTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:TestTextBox Text="xaml text"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <System:String>111</System:String>
    </ItemsControl>
<StackPanel>
```

The result is TestTextBox.Text is different in these cases - "xaml text" in first case, "ctor text" in second case.

Could someone explain why it works this way? I'd expect that TestTextBox.Text will be "xaml text" in both cases.

Comment: I assume you are deriving from TextBox (and this is where the 'Text' property is coming from), right?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing).

When you are using Templates, value precedence for dependency properties is different.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe it's the case that the value precedence is any different (dependency property precedence should always be consistent). It's more the fact that setting the value in the constructor is equivalent to setting to value locally, and local values have a higher precedence than data template values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are doing it not correct. It is actualy not rendering the TextBox as you have not given items source. Or what you can do is something like

```
<ItemsControl.Items>
                <TestTextBoxFet:TestTextBox Text="xaml text"/>
                </ItemsControl.Items>
```

Comment: No, it render the TestTextBox. Please note that there is <System:String>111</System:String> after ItemsControl.ItemTemplate setter, so string "111" is added to the items source.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gaurawerma.

The precedence of value set in constructor is higher than that set in Data Template.
Hence you see the result as different in both the cases.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a4e7ed36-9a8a-48ce-a5d5-00a49376669b